# batch command to log file

Tags: dos

I wanted to capture the contents of DOS command file (.CMD) to a log file.

I can understnd I can capture the individual commands to log file using > or >>.

However I wanted to copy the contents of the complete dos screen into a log file as well.

I have also noticed when I use >> it removes the output message ( 1 file copied) from the dos console and moves in the log file. Is it possibl I can leave the message is displaied in both console and log file.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

> However I wanted to copy the contents of the complete dos screen into a log file as well.

Make sure not to use "echo off" in your script.

> it removes the output message ( 1 file copied) from the dos console and moves in the log file

Redirect stderr to stdout before appending:

```
myscript.bat 2>&1 >> myscript.log
```

See [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_redirection.php) a good resource on batch file redirection.

> Is it possibl I can leave the message is displaied in both console and log file

You need "tee".  Download a good one for Windows from [here](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/).  Then do this instead of the above.

```
myscript.bat 2>&1 | tee -a myscript.log
```

Comment: Here is syntax of my Sample CMD file: *** XCopy C:\1\Source\Test.txt C:\1\Target\ /R/Y/K Sample.CMD 2>&1 >> C:\1\log.txt Pause *** it is copying the console output yo log file but the log file is keep increasing as it seems CMD continues to execute as a loop.

Answer (score -2):

```
myscript.bat >> myscript.log 2>&1
```